# Size Option in Vanilla

Tags: options, option-pricing

How to compute the price of a vanilla option (or a forward starting option) if there is extra optionality to change the Notional by a pre-determined percentage ($a%$, say)at some future time $t$ between Now and Maturity of the Vanilla option? In other words, at $t, 0 < t <T$ option holder can step up the Notional by $a N$, where $T$ is the maturity of the Vanilla option, $N$ is the Notional and $a$ is pre-determined contractually. For Forward Starting option time $t$ is equal to the strike date (when strike is determined in the contract). Solving either the Vanilla or Forward Starting case is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Look at compound options. Options on options

Comment: I would sell it for $(1+a)\times$ the value of the vanilla.